# How does Geofencing work on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, geofencing

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Geofencing example for Windows 10 but can't seem to get this to work, have tried adding a geofence using the emulator and map for this then adding lots of points around and doing pins, live or routes around the set geofence point but no events ever fire, even through the background task is running or it's done in the foreground while this is happening it never seems to work, have set the appropriate values in the Manifest file and get the notification to allow location access and have this, don't seem to get any exceptions just lack of any activity for the Geofence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with Geofences not being triggered in Windows 10 has been resolved in the 10240 build of Windows 10, this was an issue in prior builds but is now fixed